# WWW error: Java.net.protocol Exception: Exceeded content-length limit

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am building a Unity App. One part of that requires me to send images from the mobile device to a server. The code is working fine on the laptop, but in the mobile device it is throwing the error:

> WWW error: Java.net.protocol Exception: Exceeded content-length limit.

The script which captures and sends the image is attached below.

The methods concerned with sending the images are `sendimage(byte[])` and `WaitForRequest(WWW)`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.IO; 
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;


public class imageClient : MonoBehaviour
{
   public string deviceName;
   WebCamTexture wct;
   public string path = "";
   public string pth;
   public string responseAsString;
   byte[] data;
   Texture2D snap;
   public string response = "Request not made";

   void Start()
   {
      Debug.Log("IT has Started");
      WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;     //detecting all webcam devices
      deviceName = devices[0].name;
      wct = new WebCamTexture();                          //setting cubes texture as the webcam view and taking appropriate snapshot
      wct.deviceName = deviceName;
      wct.requestedHeight = 400;
      wct.requestedWidth = 300;
      wct.requestedFPS = 20;
      GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = wct;   
   }

   void OnGUI()
   {
      path = Application.persistentDataPath;              //path of the apk
      if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 70, 650, 120), response))
      {
         wct.Play();
         StartCoroutine(TakeSnapshot());                 //snapshot taken and sent as POST request to the server
      }
   }

   private IEnumerator TakeSnapshot()
   {
      yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();               //wait for the frame to get properly captured
      Debug.Log("0");
      Texture2D snap = new Texture2D(wct.width, wct.height);
      Debug.Log("1");
      snap.SetPixels(wct.GetPixels());
      Debug.Log("2");
      snap.Apply();
      Debug.Log("3");

      byte[] data = snap.EncodeToPNG();                   //frame image stored as png
      System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path + "/asimunmesh.png", data);
      sendimage(data);
      Debug.Log("8");
   }

   public WWW sendimage(byte[] data)
   {
      const string url = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php";  //put in the server url to which to post request 

      Debug.Log("Entering request method");

      //byte[] postData = File.ReadAllBytes(flacName);
      //Debug.Log("Read flac file. Size: " + data.Length + " bytes");

      var form = new WWWForm();
      var headers = form.headers;

      headers["Method"] = "POST";
      headers["Content-Type"] = "image/png";
      headers["Content-Length"] = data.Length.ToString();
      // headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

      form.AddBinaryData("fileUpload", data, "pngFile", "image/png");
      var httpRequest = new WWW(url, form.data, headers);
      Debug.Log("waiting for reply back");
      StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(httpRequest));
      return httpRequest;
   }

   private IEnumerator<WWW> WaitForRequest(WWW www)
   {
      yield return www;

      // check for errors
      if (www.error == null)
      {
         Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.text);
         response = "WWW Ok!: " + www.text;
      }
      else
      {
         Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
         response = "WWW Error: " + www.error;
      }
   }
}
```

I think that there is some limit set on java servlet on android on how much data it can send. 
But I doubt that this may be the reason of the error.

Update : I tried to send a simple string of 2 bytes . It also threw the same exception: Protocol exception: Exceeded content-length limit of 2 bytes

Comment: Just how large as these images? (in terms of MBs and pixels)

Comment: @VenkatatAxiomStudios images are around ~150 KB

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not exactly a solution to the problem. But I found that using UnityEngine.WWW class has some problems in android. The problem maybe with the class itself. Anyways there is an opensource Unity plugin available at Github which can help you accomplish this(making HTTP requests) on Android along with iOS and OSX.

https://github.com/imkira/unity-urlclient

This is the link of the repository and you can find the plugin.
I have tested it on Android and it seems to work fine.